# Error: Expected '' to equal undefined jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Hi I am trying to test a div text which is dynamically bind with interpolation. The data I am receiving is from API on `ngOnInit()`. How can I do proper test on that ?

Right now I am getting error - `Error: Expected '' to equal undefined`

*Spec:-*

```js
it('should check store name' , () => {
    const mypara: HTMLDivElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.ant-tag-red');
    expect(mypara).toBeTruthy();
    expect(mypara.innerHTML).toEqual(component.name);
})
```

**HTML :-**

```html
<div class="ant-tag-red">{{name}}</div>
```

**Component :**   `name: any`

Comment: Is `component.name` set anywhere? Maybe in the `ngOnInit()` Are you calling `fixture.detectChanges()` to render the template and implicitly call `ngOnInit()`?

Comment: @FabianGosebrink  No it is not set anywhere else. I have a function where I am subscribing to the API call and using that function on `ngOnInit()`. The `fixture.detectChanges()` is by default in `beforeEach` function. I am new in jamine unit testing so not much aware where I can use that

Comment: Then you either have to mock the api call or the service call and use `waitForAsync()` to wrap the test or set the property manually.

Comment: @FabianGosebrink Got it , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line instead:

```js
const mypara = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.ant-tag-red'));     
expect(mypara.nativeElement.innerText).toEqual(component.name);
```

Comment: No it didn't worked , same error. In component when I am giving some initial value ex: `name: any = 'Max'` . Then it will work. but I don't want to give any initial value as it is from API call.

Comment: @RohitGhosh, In a unit test you need to mock values as the components are needed to be tested in isolation. Therefore, i recommend to provide a value on your own in the unit test (for example by setting `component.name = 'Rohit';` manually). In reality that is the objective of unit tests, to test one thing at a time.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the approach. Also I have another issue with another component. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68833081/typeerror-cannot-read-property-status-of-undefined-jasmine-test